# Mocking objects in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, mox

I'm new to Unit testing and mocking objects in Python. I have a function that I need to create a unit test for.

```
def BuildBall(self, material):
  """Create a Ball from material."""
  result = {}
  for b in xrange(material.ball_size()):
    ball = material.ball(b)
    result[ball.name()] = (ball.name(), ball.description())
  return result
```

I want to create a dummy object(material) and pass it to BuildBall(), so that I can predict what the result will look like in my unit test.

I'm not too sure how I can pass a dummy object to my method in this case. Any idea if I can use mox to create a dummy object in my case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Somewhat related; to generate fake data: http://www.joke2k.net/faker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Python Mocker](http://labix.org/mocker) package: 
It allows you to easily generate objects that mock a certain functionality for testing. You can find a simple example [here](http://labix.org/mocker#head-d5599b191ba394ee40e90712e666037287054c10).